# Jekyll defaults to system Ruby version instead of RVM version

Tags: ruby, rvm, jekyll

I've looked through tens of posts regarding this and still can't quite figure it out/haven't found an identical situation. Basically, I have RVM with the default set to Ruby 2.0.0, but when I cd to the directory with my Jekyll page and run

```
jekyll serve
```

the result is

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 5 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/jekyll:22
```

even though in the same directory when I run

```
ruby -v
```

the result is

```
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

If I run

```
rvm use 2.0.0@project-directory
```

and then run

```
jekyll serve
```

it works like a charm.

I've tried using .rvmrc and .ruby-version files in the root, and in both cases when I cd to the directory nothing indicates that those are recognized.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your system ruby has jekyll installed, so it tells the stack trace

```
# from /usr/bin/jekyll:22
```

The reason it calls that binary before your updated jekyll is probably due to the order within your $PATH so to solve this; one option is to remove the old jekyll binary:

```
$ which jekyll #=> /usr/bin/jekyll
$ sudo rm `which jekyll`
```

That should suffice. Try again now.

In addition, given the gem was probably installed along with that binary try to remove the old gem version.

```
$ rvm use system
$ ruby -v #=> ruby 1.8.7

$ gem uninstall jekyll # add sudo if you get a permission error
```

Comment: Beautiful, that worked great. I just had to reinstall Jekyll on the 2.0.0 version with 'gem install jekyll' after making sure I had done 'rvm use 2.0.0 --default', as I forgot that the first time I installed it was with sudo in the system Ruby version (1.8). Thanks a ton!